# Problem on cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that if $G$ is a group that  contains cyclic subgroups of order $4,5$ then there must exist an element of order $20$ in $ G$.

---

I don't know how to prove it. I'm just beginner.Thanks for help .

Comment: Why are you asking us to show something that is false? Where did this problem come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false, in general! For example, if we take $G=S_5$, then $G$ has cyclic subgroups of order $4$ and $5$,but $G$ has no element of order $20$.

---

If $G$ is Abelian then this result is true! Call $H$ the cyclic subgroup of order $4$ and $K$,the cyclic subgroups of order $5$ in $G$. So $\exists a \in H \wedge b \in K$ so that $\vert a \vert=4$ and $\vert b \vert=5$.

Now, all we know is about only $a$ and $b$, so use these two to produce the another element of order $20$.

Here $ab=ba$ implies $ab$ is the required element of order $20$.